# read text from xml and load into a list c#

Tags: c#, xml, list

I save a list that contains all the `checkboxes` names that are checked in an XML file. I want to create a new list that will contains all the names of my `checkboxes` from XML (checkbox1, checkbox2, etc). How can I do that? It looks like this on XML:

```
<root>
    <Checked> //here is my list that I saved:
         <checkbox1/>
         <checkbox2>
    </Checked>
</root>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
public List<string> CheckedList
    {
        get
        {
            return _listkey;
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in GetNodeByName(Checked, Const.root).ChildNodes)
            {
                _listKey.Add(...)
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.load(CheckBoxesXml);

    XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes(@"/root/Checked");

    List<String> checked = new List<String>();
    foreach(XmlNode node in list)
        checked.Add(node.Name);
```